# Javadoc tag for the institution

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

I'm not sure if it is appropriate to use it, but is there a Javadoc tag for the company/institution/organization one works at? Something similar to `@author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full list of the supported tags is given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDJGIJB). As you can see, there is no tag for the author's organization/institution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard tag for this, but you can always define your own one using Javadoc's -tag option: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#tag

This will work for simple tags such as `@author`, so it might be sufficient for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The guide [How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@author) has an example of referring to entities and uses `@author` tags at package level.

> In these days of the community process when development of new APIs is an open, joint effort, the JSR can be consider the author for new packages at the package level. For example, the new package java.nio has "@author JSR-51 Expert Group" at the package level.

There doesn't seem to be any restriction that the author tag has to include only a name. So another option is to simply add the information to the actual author, like `@author John Doe (Acme Corporation)`.